# What is the Tuma status of food which touched a corpse?

Tags: halacha, food, death, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

In general (DeOraisa), when Tumah spreads it lowers itself by a level. Moreover, a Keli can't make a Keli Tamei, nor can a food item make another food item Tamei (at least by Chullin). So a "classical" spreading is:

1. Av Hatuma - a Zav/Sheretz ->
2. Rishon - Person/Keli ->
3. Sheni - food

or

1. Av Hatuma - a Zav/Sheretz ->
2. Rishon - food/drink ->
3. Sheni - drink/food (respectively)

What happens if a corpse touches a food item, can it spread between food/drinks like

1. Avi Avos Hatuma - corpse ->
2. Av Hatuma - food ->
3. Rishon - drink ->
4. Sheini - food

or do we say that the first "food" becomes a "rishon" and can only spread once to a "sheini"?

Comment: Did you ask this in chat once? We've definitely discussed this before.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes I did. Then I realized that it was somewhat of a real question and that it probably should be on the main page, but forgot about it until now.

Comment: Can you grab the link then? I recall there were some sources proffered already.

Comment: Tosafos (*P'sachim* 17a) says that, vis-a-vis transmitting *tum'ah* to other foods, food that touched a corpse is like an *av*, but vis-a-vis transmitting *tum'ah* to people or vessels, it is not considered an *av*.  ([Chat comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11218330#11218330); [another chat comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11164405#11164405)).

Answer (score 1):

The kehati on pesachim chapter 1 mishna 6 says that min hatorah food does not contaminate other food but the Rabbis decreed that it does.

However, that mishna does say that food that is impure may make other food impure, even if only rabinically.

---

The Kehati on Chagiga 3:3 brings the idea (From [Parah 8:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37950&pgnum=320)) that there is a rabinical decree that when water touches something impure, that water becomes a Rishon LeTumah, regardless of the degree of impurity the item that made the water impure was.

Comment: Does R Kehati mention which earlier commentaries he is basing himself on?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Not that I remember, but the Bartenura says the same thing

Comment: that's Ochel Metame Ochel (see Gemara). My question is ochel->mashke->ochel.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: perhaps the question can use some clarification. for example, _"can it spread between food/drinks"_ seems to indicate food **or** drink.