# What happens when food or vessels or a tent become Tumeh? Do they transmite Tumeh to others?

Tags: talmud-gemara, halacha-theory, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

What are the ramifications of vessels of food that become tumah?  What happens if some one eats Tumeh foods or touches a vessel or article of clothing or tent that is tumeh?  Do these things transmit tumeh, if they do how severe is it?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31904

Comment: VTClose as Too Broad.

Comment: Learn the 30 chapters of Mishnayot Keilim to get all these answers. It depends on how Tamei they are.